# using falcor for a multi parameter request with transient data

Tags: falcor

I'm having trouble getting my head around how to use Falcor for a particular use case.

Basically I need to take a few fields from a page and execute server side validation business logic.  The page should just display whether the validation was successful or not and if not, the reason.

I could technically use a falcor get query, but they don't seem suited to multi-parameter calls

I could try and use a Falcor 'call', which would allow me to easily pass through multiple parameters, but is not suited to returning transient data.

Is this just a use case that Falcor should not really be used for or am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

All the data returned by a Falcor server is part of the model, transient or not.

A `get` is appropriate here because you want to *read* data. `call` are appropriate to make black box *modifications* to the model.

`get`s are always multi-parameters because you give the entire path of the data which can enclose whatever you want. Let's say we want to validate a URL. We could do something like:

```
getValue('updateProfileForm.website["http://example.com"].valid')
```

And that would return true of false depending on the URL. The result can be kept in cache eternally since it will never change (a URL is either always valid or it is not).

If the validation process needs to know the value of multiple fields at once, like password confirmation, you can do something like this:

```
getValue('updateProfileForm.password["new password"].confirm["new password"].valid')
```

If the validation depends on something external to the form, like what time it is, include this parameter in the path to maximize cache-ability.